# Tracking various stats on character development

Tags: lua

The purpose of this code is to track player development on a Multi-User Dungeon I play. It allows saving multiple characters to the same database. It allows for updates on level, hour, tier, morts, months, years, weeks, and days.

Are there any improvements that could be made? Assume that any "missing" functions are functions I have elsewhere that have no real impact; this is the bulk of the code. Ultimately, I want to condense the code from the current 224 lines, if possible.

```
function report_type(rtype)
  local reports = {["hour"] = "ThisHour",  ["lasthour"] = "LastHour",  ["today"] = "Today",  ["yesterday"] = "Yesterday",  ["tier"] = "ThisTier",  ["lasttier"] = "LastTier",  ["month"] = "ThisMonth",  ["lastmonth"] = "LastMonth",  ["year"] = "ThisYear",  ["lastyear"] = "LastYear",  ["mort"] = "ThisMort",  ["lastmort"] = "LastMort",  ["week"] = "ThisWeek",  ["lastweek"] = "LastWeek"}
  if rtype == "lastlevel" then
    if trackerdb[charname]["HasPupped"] == 0 then
      return report_info("LastLevel")
    else
      return report_info("LastLevel","Pup")
    end
  elseif rtype == "level" then
    if trackerdb[charname]["HasPupped"] == 0 then
      return report_info("ThisLevel")
    else
      return report_info("ThisLevel","Pup")
    end
  else 
  return report_info(reports[rtype])
  end -- if
end -- function report_type

function QuestStart(t, r, a, c)

  trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"] = "@x184{@x160On Quest@x184} @wKill @x160" .. t .. " @wLocation: @x160" .. r .. "@w in @x160" .. a .. "@w.  Time to complete: @x160" .. c .. "@w minutes."
  trackerdb[charname]["Timers"]["ThisQuest"]["Start"]=socket.gettime()
  savetable()
  return trackerdb[charname]["ReportChan"] .. " " .. trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"]
end

function QuestFail()
  trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"] = "@x184{@x160Quest failed@x184}@w"
  addto(trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Total"],"Failed")
  savetable()
  return trackerdb[charname]["ReportChan"] .. " " .. trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"]
end

function QuestKilled()
  return "qc"
end

function QuestComp(q, tq, p, tr, tp, m, l, d, da, qp, g, c, w)

  local mult, bonus = "", ""

  trackerdb[charname]["Timers"]["LastQuest"]["Time"] = update_time("ThisQuest")
  quest_update(qp, g, tp, p, tr, da, d, c)
  return trackerdb[charname]["ReportChan"] .. " " .. trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"]

end

function QuestReady()
  return trackerdb[charname]["ReportChan"] .. " @x184{@x160Quest ready@x184}@w"
end

function QuestTimeout()
  trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"] = "@x184{@x160Quest timed out@x184}@w"
  addto(trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Total"],"Failed")
  savetable()
  return trackerdb[charname]["ReportChan"] .. " " .. trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"]
end

function QuestReset()
  return trackerdb[charname]["ReportChan"] .. " " .. "@x184{@x160Quest reset@x184}"
end

function addto(t,k,v)
  t[k]=t[k]+(v or 1)
end

function subfrom(t,k,v)
  t[k]=t[k]-(v or 1)
end

function timediff(t2,t1)
  local d1,d2,carry,diff = os.date('*t',t1),os.date('*t',t2),false,{}
  local colMax = {60,60,24,os.date('*t',os.time{year=d1.year,month=d1.month+1,day=0}).day,12}
  d2.hour = d2.hour - (d2.isdst and 1 or 0) + (d1.isdst and 1 or 0) -- handle dst
  for i,v in ipairs({'sec','min','hour','day','month','year'}) do
    diff[v] = d2[v] - d1[v] + (carry and -1 or 0)
    carry = diff[v] < 0
    if carry then diff[v] = diff[v] + colMax[i] end
  end
  return diff
end

function addZero(n)
  if n < 10 then
    n = "0" .. n
  end
  return n
end

function iffunc(k,str,str1)
  if k ~= "" and k ~= 0 then
    return str .. k .. (str1 or "")
  else
    return ""
  end
end

function iif(cond,tru,fls) --inline if, instead of C's (cond ? tru:fls)
  if cond then
    return tru
  else
    return fls
  end
end

-- Start Tracker Revamp

function init_tracker(pname, reset)
  local trackertemplate = {}
  trackerdb[pname] = table.load("C:/MUSHclient/Tables/trackertemplate.tbl")
  local ttable = trackerdb[pname]
  local resettime = socket.gettime()
  for k,_ in pairs(ttable["Timers"]) do
    if k["Start"] then
    ttable["Timers"][k]["Start"] = resettime
  end
  end
  ttable["HasPupped"]=0
  if reset then print(pname,"has been reset!")
  else
    print(pname,"has been initialized!")
  end
  savetable()
end

function campaign_update(qp, gold, trivia, pracs, trains, mobs)
  local cptable = trackerdb[charname]["Campaigns"]["Total"]
  addto(cptable,"Qp",tonumber(qp))
  addto(cptable,"Gold",tonumber(gold))
  addto(cptable,"Trivia",tonumber(trivia))
  addto(cptable,"Pracs",tonumber(pracs))
  addto(cptable,"Trains",tonumber(trains))
  exp_update(0, tonumber(gold), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, tonumber(trivia), 0, tonumber(pracs), tonumber(trains), tonumber(qp), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
  trackerdb[charname]["Campaigns"]["Report"] = "@x184{@x160Campaign Completed@x184} @wTime: @x160" .. trackerdb[charname]["Timers"]["LastCampaign"]["Time"] .. " @wMobs: @x160"..mobs.." @wQps: @x160" .. qp .. " @wGold: @x160" .. commas(gold) .. iffunc(pracs," @wPracs: @x160") .. iffunc(trains, " @wTrains: @x160") .. iffunc(trivia, " @wTrivia: @x160")
end

function quest_update(qp, gold, trivia, pracs, trains, daily, double, completed)
  local qtable = trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Total"]
  local xtable = trackerdb[charname]["Exp"]
  addto(qtable,"Qp",tonumber(qp))
  addto(qtable,"Gold",tonumber(gold))
  addto(qtable,"Trivia",tonumber(trivia))
  addto(qtable,"Pracs",tonumber(pracs))
  addto(qtable,"Trains",tonumber(trains))
  addto(qtable,"Completed")
  multiplier = tonumber(daily)+tonumber(double)+1
  exp_update(0, tonumber(gold), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, tonumber(trivia), 0, tonumber(pracs), tonumber(trains), tonumber(qp), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  trackerdb[charname]["Quests"]["Report"] = "@x184{@x160Quest #" .. completed .. "@x184} @wTime: @x160" .. trackerdb[charname]["Timers"]["LastQuest"]["Time"] .. " @wQps: @x160" .. qp .. iif(tonumber(daily)==1 or tonumber(double)==1," @x184(with " .. iif(multiplier==2,"double","triple") .. ")","") .. " @wGold: @x160" .. commas(gold) .. iffunc(pracs," @wPracs: @x160") .. iffunc(trains, " @wTrains: @x160") .. iffunc(trivia, " @wTrivia: @x160")
end

function exp_update_actual(vars)
  local blocks = {"ThisHour", "ThisLevel", "Today", "ThisWeek", "ThisMonth", "ThisYear", "ThisMort", "ThisTier"}
  local xtable = trackerdb[charname]["Exp"]

  for i, block in ipairs(blocks) do
    for key, value in pairs(vars) do
      if block=="ThisLevel" and key=="Levels" then
        xtable[block][key]=0
      else
        xtable[block][key]=xtable[block][key]+value
      end
    end
  end
  savetable()
end

function exp_update(xp, gold, kills, str, con, dex, wis, int, luck, trivia, btrains, pracs, trains, qp, quests, pups, levels, bonusxp, campaigns)
  local vars =
  {
  Exp = tonumber(xp) or 0,
  Gold = tonumber(gold) or 0,
  Kills = tonumber(kills) or 0,
  BonusStr = tonumber(str) or 0,
  BonusCon = tonumber(con) or 0,
  BonusDex = tonumber(dex) or 0,
  BonusWis = tonumber(wis) or 0,
  BonusInt = tonumber(int) or 0,
  BonusLuck = tonumber(luck) or 0,
  Trivia = tonumber(trivia) or 0,
  BonusTrains = tonumber(btrains) or 0,
  Pracs = tonumber(pracs) or 0,
  Trains = tonumber(trains) or 0,
  Qp = tonumber(qp) or 0,
  Quests = tonumber(quests) or 0,
  Pups = tonumber(pups) or 0,
  Levels = tonumber(levels) or 0,
  BonusExp = tonumber(bonusxp) or 0,
  Campaigns = tonumber(campaigns) or 0,
  }
  exp_update_actual(vars)
end

function update_time(field)
  local ttable = trackerdb[charname]["Timers"][field]
  local tupdate = timediff(iif(ttable["End"],ttable["End"],socket.gettime()), ttable["Start"])
  return iffunc(tupdate.year,"","y ") .. iffunc(tupdate.month,"","m ") .. iffunc(tupdate.day,"","d ") .. iffunc(tupdate.hour,"",":") .. addZero(tupdate.min) .. ":" ..  addZero(tupdate.sec)
end

function history_update(field)
  local ttype = iif(field=="Today","Today","This"..field)
  local ltype = iif(field=="Today","Yesterday","Last"..field)
  trackerdb[charname]["Exp"][ltype] = trackerdb[charname]["Exp"][ttype]
  for k,v in pairs(trackerdb[charname]["Exp"][ttype]) do
    --trackerdb[charname]["Exp"][ltype][k]=v
    trackerdb[charname]["Exp"][ttype][k]=0
  end
end

function report_info(field, wild)
  local wild = wild or ""
  local rtable = trackerdb[charname]["Exp"][field]
  local reporttime = ""
  if field == "ThisLevel" or field == "ThisMort" or field == "ThisTier" then
    reporttime = " @wTime: @x160"..update_time(field)
  elseif field == "LastMort" or field == "LastTier" or field == "LastLevel" then
    reporttime = " @wTime: @x160"..trackerdb[charname]["Timers"][field]["Time"]
  end

  local reportbon = iffunc(rtable["BonusStr"]," @wS@x184{@x160","@x184}") .. iffunc(rtable["BonusInt"]," @wI@x184{@x160","@x184}") .. iffunc(rtable["BonusWis"]," @wW@x184{@x160","@x184}") .. iffunc(rtable["BonusDex"]," @wD@x184{@x160","@x184}") .. iffunc(rtable["BonusCon"]," @wC@x184{@x160","@x184}") .. iffunc(rtable["BonusLuck"]," @wL@x184{@x160","@x184}")

  return " @x184{@x160" .. iif(wild~="", string.gsub(field, "^(%u%l+)%u%l+","%1 "..wild), string.gsub(field,"^(%u%l+)(%u%l+)","%1 %2")) .. "@x184}" .. iif(reporttime,reporttime) .. iif(rtable["Levels"],iffunc(rtable["Levels"]," @wLevels: @x160"),"") .. iif(rtable["Pups"],iffunc(rtable["Pups"]," @wPups: @x160"),"") .. " @wExp: @x160" .. commas(rtable["Exp"]+rtable["BonusExp"]) .. " @w(@x160" .. commas(rtable["BonusExp"]) .. " bonus@w) Kills: @x160" .. commas(rtable["Kills"]) .. " @wGold: @x160" .. commas(rtable["Gold"]) .. iif(rtable["Trains"]>0," @wTrains: @x160" .. rtable["Trains"] .. " @w(@x160" .. rtable["BonusTrains"] .. " bonus@w)","") .. iif(rtable["Pracs"]>0," @wPracs: @x160" .. rtable["Pracs"],"") .. iif(rtable["Quests"]>0," @wQuests: @x160" .. rtable["Quests"],"") .. iif(rtable["Campaigns"]>0," @wCampaigns: @x160" .. rtable["Campaigns"],"") .. iif(rtable["Qp"]>0," @w(@x160" .. rtable["Qp"] .. " qps@w)", "") .. iif(rtable["Trivia"]>0," @wTrivia: @x160" .. rtable["Trivia"],"") .. iffunc(reportbon," @wBonus Stats:") .. "@w"
end
-- End tracker revamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your first function: `report_type`. You don't need to put the table indices inside square brackets.

```
local reports = { hour = "ThisHour",  lasthour = "LastHour",  ... }
```

would work just as well. Instead of checking `HasPupped` in each of the `if` blocks, check it just once.

```
function report_type(rtype)
    local reports = {
        hour = "ThisHour", 
        lasthour = "LastHour", 
        today = "Today", 
        yesterday = "Yesterday", 
        tier = "ThisTier", 
        lasttier = "LastTier", 
        month = "ThisMonth", 
        lastmonth = "LastMonth", 
        year = "ThisYear", 
        lastyear = "LastYear", 
        mort = "ThisMort", 
        lastmort = "LastMort", 
        week = "ThisWeek", 
        lastweek = "LastWeek"
    }
    local bHasPup = ( trackerdb[charname]["HasPupped"] == 0 and "Pup" )
    if rtype == "lastlevel" then
        return report_info( "LastLevel", bHasPup )
    elseif rtype == "level" then
        return report_info( "ThisLevel", bHasPup )
    else
        return report_info(reports[rtype])
    end -- if
end -- function report_type
```

You can use [`os.difftime`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.difftime) instead of computing your own time difference.

As for your `addZero` function, I think you can simply use a `string.format` call:

```
function addZero( n )
    return ("%02d"):format( n )
end
```

I'm still going through rest of the function definitions. I'll keep updating this post.

Comment: The timediff function is something I came across in the past that would return xx years xx months xx days xx hours xx minutes xx seconds, and I modified it to suit my needs. Not sure if it's the most efficient, however. And thanks for responding!

Comment: Ever get around to the rest of the function definitions?

Comment: @Josh The rest of the code looks okay. You can probably use the OOP approach, but that'd be your own choice. It'll make the code easier to read as well. If you want, you could also implement [closures](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html).